# How can I separate this conversation into per row using python,

Tags: python, regex, string, split

Lets say this string below is a content of a row with a "body" as the column name. Now I want to create a row per speaker out from this string.

**Helper:**
Hi, I'm Helper, Virtual Assistant, how can I help you today?
Are you inquiring about:
eBooks
Audiobooks
Purchasing
Subscriptions
Movies
etc

**Cx said:**
Movies

The expected output should be like:

| Speaker | Transcript |
| --- | --- |
| Helper | Hi, I'm Helper, Virtual Assistant, how can I help you today? Are you inquiring about:eBooksAudiobooks Purchasing Subscriptions Movies etc |
| Cx said | Movies |

I have tried this but the

```py
Testresult = tempchatdf.body.str.split(":\*\*",expand = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just take the `str` and `split(":")`.

```py
split = string.split(":")
result = [split[0], ":".join(split[1:])]
```

This takes the first split and makes that the speaker (0th index) then combines the rest of the split with ":". This is done to ensure that any extra ":" comes back.

If the string contains several lines of these, you can just wrap it in a loop.

```py
table = []
for line in string:
    split = string.split(":")
    table.append([split[0], ":".join(split[1:])])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to match the `body` string and creating a new df

```py
row_str = df["body"].values[0]
data = re.findall(r'(.+?):\s*(.+)', row_str)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Speaker", "Transcript"])
print(new_df)
```

Or you can use re with [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) in a list comprehension

```py
pattern = r'^([a-zA-Z\s]+):'
rows = [{"Speaker": re.match(pattern, line).group(1).strip(), 
         "Transcript": line.split(":", 1)[1].strip()}
         for line in df["body"].str.split("\n").explode().tolist()
         if re.match(pattern, line)]

new_df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
print(new_df)
```

| Speaker | Transcript |
| --- | --- |
| Helper | Hi, I'm Helper, Virtual Assistant, how can I help you today? Are you inquiring about:eBooksAudiobooks Purchasing Subscriptions Movies etc |
| Cx said | Movies |